# Autocomplete event when scrolled to bottom

Tags: angular, primeng

I have implemented primeng-autocomplete and I need to load next elements when scrolling ends. I have gone through primeng closed issues and find this one:

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/513

this is closed, but any idea how to implement this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have workaround but I hope someone has a better option.
Angular v.7, primeng v.7:

in template:

1. Add completeMethod:

```
<p-autoComplete
  #autocompletePanel
  (completeMethod)="completeHandler($event)">
  ...
</p-autocomplete>
```

in *.ts file:

1. add reference to autocomplete:

```
@ViewChild('autocompletePanel') autocompletePanel;
```

2. inject Renderer2 in constructor:

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2){}
```

3. add handler:

```
public completeHandler(): void {
//you need to wait for panel to be added to the DOM (any better solutions?)
  setTimeout(() => {
    const autocompletePanel = this.autocompletePanel.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.ui-autocomplete-panel');
    if (autocompletePanel) {
      this.renderer.listen(autocompletePanel, 'scroll', event => {
        if ((event.target.scrollHeight - event.target.clientHeight) === event.target.scrollTop)) {
          // ... handle it
          console.log('scrolled to the bottom of the panel');
        }
      }
    }
  }, 500);
}
```